# Would it be possible to combine these SQL select statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql/mariadb.

What I want to do: Get `id`, `name`, `private` for each `Group` / then get the number of `Video`s in each `Group` / then get the last 20 `Video`s for each `Group`.

Right now, I use three separate SQL queries, and then run it each time for each respective id. Is there a way to combine the three SQL queries into one, and run them over a list of ids?

For example, on groups 1,2,3:

```
Executing (default): select `id`, `name`, `private` from `Groups` where `id` = '1' limit 1
Executing (default): select `id`, `name`, `private` from `Groups` where `id` = '2' limit 1
Executing (default): select `id`, `name`, `private` from `Groups` where `id` = '3' limit 1

Executing (default): select count(*) from `Videos` where `GroupId` = '1' and `live` = true
Executing (default): select count(*) from `Videos` where `GroupId` = '2' and `live` = true
Executing (default): select count(*) from `Videos` where `GroupId` = '3' and `live` = true

Executing (default): select `id`, `file` from `Videos` where `GroupId` = '1' and `live` = true order by `id` desc limit 20
Executing (default): select `id`, `file` from `Videos` where `GroupId` = '2' and `live` = true order by `id` desc limit 20
Executing (default): select `id`, `file` from `Videos` where `GroupId` = '3' and `live` = true order by `id` desc limit 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IN`

```
Executing (default): (SELECT `id`, `name`, `private` FROM `Groups` WHERE`id` = '1' LIMIT 1)
                     UNION ALL
                     (SELECT `id`, `name`, `private` FROM `Groups` WHERE`id` = '2' LIMIT 1)
                     UNION ALL
                     (SELECT `id`, `name`, `private` FROM `Groups` WHERE`id` = '3' LIMIT 1)

Executing (default): SELECT count(*) 
                     FROM `Videos` 
                     WHERE `GroupId` IN ('1', '2', '3')  AND `live` = true

Executing (default): (SELECT `id`, `file` FROM `Videos` WHERE`GroupId` = '1' AND `live` = true ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20)
                     UNION ALL
                     (SELECT `id`, `file` FROM `Videos` WHERE`GroupId` = '2' AND `live` = true ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20)
                     UNION ALL
                     (SELECT `id`, `file` FROM `Videos` WHERE`GroupId` = '3' AND `live` = true ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20)
```

Comment: Could I efficiently break down the three queries into one or two queries or is this the minimum number of queries required to get the necessary data?

Comment: Depends if the tables have a link to each other and how you want the data to be output

Comment: It only gives first record of 1/2/3 but questioner needs all three records

Comment: Updated to return desired result